# Start ContentPage in BroadcastReceiver OnReceive method C# MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

So i have code where `AlarmManager` starts `OnReceive` method of `BroadcastReceiver`. Than i need to start there a `ContentPage`.

So the problem is that i cannot do it like

```
var navigationPage = Microsoft.Maui.Cntrols.Application.Current.Windows as NavigationPage;
await navigationPage.PushAsync(nextPage);
```

because navigationPage is Null.

Also i cannot do it like

```
var newPageIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NewPage));
            newPageIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            context.StartActivity(newPageIntent);
```

because `NewPage` is not `Activity`.
There is a chance that i can do it by starting `Activity`, but than question how to start `ContentPage` in `Activity?`

Comment: what is the type of the current `MainPage`?

Comment: Cn't you trigger `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Jason `ContentPage`.
@FreakyAli for what? Are you saying that i can start `MainActivity`, that can start `MainPage`, than how to start exacly `NewPage`?

Comment: if its a `ContentPage` then of course you can't convert it to a `NavigationPage`.  Try wrapping the `ContentPage` in a `NavigationPage`, then you should be able to cast it and use `PushAsync`

Comment: `var nextPage = new NewPage();
// Get the NavigationPage from the current page's Navigation property
 var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.Windows as NavigationPage);

// Push the new page onto the navigation stack
await navigationPage.PushAsync(nextPage);`
@Jason this is what i tried.
It is creating new `NavigationPage`, so there is no error but this code don't display `ContentPage`, and thats my problem.

Comment: please do not stuff code into comments.  Creating a **new** navigation page will not help.  You need to do it when you first assign the `MainPage` in your app

Comment: @Jason i haven't quite understood what have you meant by "to do it when you first assign the MainPage in your app"

Comment: in your `App` class when you initially set the `MainPage`: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WhateverMyMainPageIsCalled());`